# How we can search on our own SQLite ?

Tags: android, sqlite

I've a Sqlite with many tables and I want to make a `TextBox` which is able to search on SQL , How can I do this?

Comment: You need tutorials (plural), not one question on stackoverflow. I recommend you search Google instead. And try to learn piece-by-piece. With all due respect, this is not a help desk that we give you entire code solutions, but a place to ask specific (punctual) problems and learn more in the process.

Comment: Indeed, you should try working through a tutorial that includes code using Sqlite and adapt that knowledge to your purposes...you might start with something like this: http://coenraets.org/blog/android-samples/androidtutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: That Question is too big of a scope. Second: You usually don't want people to search your entire DB... for obvious reasons: Content they should not see, like Passwords of other users. 
So you have to compile a List of all contents that should be searchable first. On each of those tables in your DB you can search the columns by for example:

```
SELECT linkToResource FROM tableName WHERE allowedContent1 like '%searchphrase%' or allowedContent2 like '%searchphrase%';
```

This is assuming you have a Table shaped like `ID, linkToResource, allowedContent1, allowedContent2, secretContent1, secretContent2`

In Android that statement looks like this:

```
    public List<String> getLinksToSearchResults(String searchphrase) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor c = yourDatabase.query(
            "yourTableName", 
            new String[] { "linkToResource" }, // The column you want as a result of the Query
            "allowedContent1 like '%?%' OR allowedContent2 like '%?%'", // The where-Clause of the statement with placeholders (?)
            new String[] { searchphrase, searchphrase }, // One String for every Placeholder-? in the where-Clause
            null, // if you like a order by put it here
            null, // group by here
            null  // having here
            );
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        result.add(c.getString(0));
    }
    c.close();
    return result;
}
```

You retrieve a String from a EditText like this:

```
String searchphrase = searchphraseEditText.getText();
```

Here is hoping you got an idea of it :D
Next time please provide some code with a more precise problem (e.g. "Why won't the following code return a four digit int?")

Enjoy!