# Sqlite search, how to?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm following http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html to create a searchable activity for my app. I'm using sqlite for db. An example "doMySearch(query)" (please see the link) for sqlite is what I'm looking for.

```
public class SearchableActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
      doMySearch(query);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What error are you encountering?

Comment: The docs for sqlite: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Comment: I'm a total noob to all this stuff. Suffices to say that I have no knowledge in sqlite. I'm looking for a tutorial containing the doMySearch(query) or something like that for sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these are the good ideas if you wanna take them :P

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742

Hope these will helps you...

Comment: just found a similer closed topic. I think i can make do with that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204606/how-we-can-search-on-our-own-sqlite